# Doctrine2 cannot make '2' one-to-many relations

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, yaml, one-to-many

I'm trying to make 3 entities (Item, Agree, Disagree) with following relations.

- Item one-to-many Agree
- Item one-to-many Disagree

But only one relation (declared later) out of two has made.

Here're my .yml files.

---

```
Entities\Item:
  type: entity
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  oneToMany:
    agrees:
      targetEntity: Agree
      mappedBy: items
  oneToMany:
    disagrees:
      targetEntity: Disagree
      mappedBy: items
```

---

```
Entities\Agree:
  type: entity
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  manyToOne:
    items:
      targetEntity: Item
      inversedBy: agrees
```

---

```
Entities\Disagree:
  type: entity
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  manyToOne:
    items:
      targetEntity: Item
      inversedBy: disagrees
```

---

And the code below is the Item.php auto-generated by Doctrine2. As you can see, it doesn't contains 'Agree' at all.

---

```
namespace Entities;

class Item {
    private $id;
    private $disagrees;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->disagrees = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function addDisagrees(\Entities\Disagree $disagrees) {
        $this->disagrees[] = $disagrees;
    }

    public function getDisagrees() {
        return $this->disagrees;
    }
}
```

---

If I switches the declaration order ('Disagree' first, followed by'Agree', like the below), Item.php has only 'Agree'-related code in this time.

---

```
Entities\Item:
  type: entity
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  oneToMany:
    disagrees:
      targetEntity: Disagree
      mappedBy: items
  oneToMany:
    agrees:
      targetEntity: Agree
      mappedBy: items
```

---

What's wrong with my code? Any comments will be helpful.

Item, Agree and Disagree are just samples to show this problem. In real project, Agree and Disagrees are totally different entity. So, don't suggest me to merge them into unified entity. :)

Answer (score 8):

You were close, you just need to put all same association mapping types under the same type declaration :)

```
  oneToMany:
    agrees:
      targetEntity: Agree
      mappedBy: items  
    disagrees:
      targetEntity: Disagree
      mappedBy: items
```