# Symfony2/Doctrine manyToOne-relationship does not appear in tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-one

I'm working with a Doctrine schema, but ran into trouble because one of the manyToOne-relationships won't persist in the database. I am clueless why this is the case, because to my eye, the syntax looks correct.

Can anyone identify the problem?

Below is my schema in yaml. There are no tables relating these two entities in my mysql-database after running 
`php app\console doctrine:schema:update --force`.

```yml
Me\MyBundle\Entity\FreeTextField:
  type: entity
  table: null
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    name:
      type: string
    flagPrivate:
      type: boolean
    description:
      type: text
      nullable: TRUE
  oneToMany:
    entries:
      targetEntity: FreeTextEntry
      mappedBy: xfield

  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }

Me\MyBundle\Entity\FreeTextEntry:
  type: entity
  table: null
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    content:
      type: text

  manyToOne:
    xfield:
      targetEntity: FreeTextField
      inversedBy: entries
  manyToOne:
    registration:
      targetEntity: Registration
      inversedBy: freeTextEntries
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: I am not sure on how to yawl syntax is declared, but why do you set the _table_ key to _null_?

Comment: It's just telling Doctrine to use whatever (default) name for the table. It was autogenerated, actually a pointless row, but not the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propably the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818097/doctrine2-cannot-make-2-one-to-many-relations). You need to put all the manyToOne -type associations under the same type declaration in Entity\FreeTextEntry, like so:

```
manyToOne:
  xfield:
    targetEntity: FreeTextField
    inversedBy: entries
  registration:
    targetEntity: Registration
    inversedBy: freeTextEntries
```